# hg notify gives "interrupted" on push

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension

I have a tortoise repository on my local machine. I would like to send notification mails on push.

On pushing the changes, all that gives is the message "interrupted!". I could not figure out the exact issue. Can someone help to get know more details on the error.

<< Output after push >>

```
% hg push http://localhost/mercurial/test_mail
pushing to http://localhost/mercurial/test_mail
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 3 changesets with 3 changes to 2 files
[command completed successfully Thu Jan 31 09:07:39 2019]
interrupted!
```

<<.hg/hgrc>> inside that repository

```
[extensions]
notify = 

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
#commit.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = Testing Email Notifications <mailid@company.com>
method = smtp

[smtp]
host = localhost

[notify]
sources = serve serve push pull bundle
test =False
template =
  details:   {baseurl}/{webroot}/rev/{node|short}
  branches:  {branches}
  changeset: {rev}:{node|short}
  user:      {author}
  date:      {date|date}
  description:
  {desc}\n

maxdiff = 1000

[usersubs]
# key is subscriber email, value is comma-separated list of glob patterns
abc@gmail.com = *

[reposubs]
* = mailid@company.com

[web]
baseurl = http://localhost/mercurial/
```